# Not-understandable WinRT Errors

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm working on an UWP Project and some weird errors are showing up in my Debug that I can't track down.

The error Message is as follows:
onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!7C5C44D2: (caller: 7C5C4327) ReturnHr(8) tid(35fc) 80070490 Element nicht gefunden. (Element not found)

What may cause this? I am getting these errors all accross my application (only using a NavigationView in my MainPage.xaml).

Comment: When you use a debugger then the OS component gets chatty, trying to help you diagnose a possible exception that might make your app fail.  Equivalent to Debug.WriteLine() in a C# program.  Important because this is C++ code and the normally helpful stack trace you'd get for an exception in a C# program gets a lot less helpful in a UWP app since it can't show that code.  If you didn't actually get a C# exception then this is not much to worry about.  The only other hint is that the machine's monitor configuration is odd.

Comment: Has your program crashed like this? Do you know what operation you do causes such an error? And can you show the relevant code for your navigationView?